# How to change the value of a parameter in the registry with the path of the selected document?

Tags: powershell, registry, contextmenu

I want to create a context menu function to copy the path of the clicked document to the registry.

I tried to create a working script, but I couldn't. This is my first powershell script. I searched for information on the internet and I couldn't find a way to add a path to the document in the registry. Running this script does not change the value of the **Path** parameter.

If I replace **%L** with a string or integer in the script, it will work normally. But I don't know how to get the path of the document so I can save the path in the registry.

**How to change the value of a parameter in the registry with the path of the selected document?** Please help me with a piece of advice or a solution to my question.

[image]

The location of the section where the path is to be saved:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Test
```

Section parameters:

[image]

The powershell script I used:

```
PowerShell -command {Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Test" -Name "Path" -Value %L}
```

Script location in the registry :

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Copy file path\command
```

Comment: Why does your script call PowerShell when it already is a PowerShell script according to _"The powershell script I used"_ ??

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand the meaning of your question. This script is not called from PowerShell.

Comment: Well.. You say you have a PowerShell script that should add something into the registry. Then.. why start it off with `PowerShell -Command ...` This simply calls another powershell instance to do the work? Adding scripts in the registry is really not-done IMO and also extremely dangerous because anyone with access can then alter your script into something malicious.

Comment: Then how should these scripts or actions be executed correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to replace the parentheses **{}** with **"** and put the path between the two **'** and instead of **%L** I had to put **%1**. I don't know why without these fixes the script wouldn't work.  In the command, use **%1** as a placeholder for the path to the file that was right-clicked.

Example: `PowerShell -command "Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Test -Name Path -Value 'C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\shellext.dll'"`

**Final script:** `PowerShell -command "Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Test -Name Path -Value '%1'"`